# Ubuntu 22.04 - 8.8.8.8 DNS is set on the server but not in resolve.cnf

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, dns

This is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

However, `resolvectl status` gives

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens160)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
```

I didn't set anything but it prints `8.8.8.8`. I would like to know why such a thing happens. The server must send arequest to a domain that only accepts some range of IPs, and I can't do that. It reports the error  `AWS HTTP error: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to xxxxx.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using systemd resolved as a local DNS cache it seems. That is why the content of /etc/resolv.conf points to a loopback device. This is where the systemd daemon listens for dns requests.

This is standard behaviour for Ubuntu on desktop, and I guess, also for servers? Anyone please elaborate here.

This is a similar setup to other daemons such as dnsmasq for example, that combined with the resolvconf scripts can do the same.

My guess is that your server has had its configuration handed to it via DHCP on your network.

But try to look in the config files for systemd in /etc/systemd in order to see, if Googles 8.8.8.8 is set there somewhere.

Going into network config in systemd in a discussion thread like this is probably going to be counter productive - it is a rather large topic. I suggest you start with a resource like this on linode and compare to your current config.

https://www.linode.com/docs/products/compute/compute-instances/guides/systemd-networkd/